# How to secure my Google Cloud Function (gen 2, pythong 3.11) for access only through my web app and iOS app?

Tags: python, swift, authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a python function running on Google Cloud (gen 2). I'm calling the function from my iOS app (using URLSession on Swift) and web app (using axios on JavaScript) as a regular REST API. Initially, I had trouble accessing it so I set the flag `--allow-unauthenticated` when deploying using gcloud CLI. Now, I'm about to push my app to production and I want to ensure that this function can not be accessed by everyone.

How can I set up authentication for my cloud function and implement in my iOS and web apps?

For more context, this is the command I use for deploying my function.

```
gcloud beta functions deploy function_name --region=us-central1 --source=src --runtime=python311 --gen2 --entry-point=main --memory=512Mb --min-instances=1 --max-instances=100 --timeout=120s --trigger-http --allow-unauthenticated --cpu=1 --concurrency=100
```

Comment: Which authentication mechanism do you use? Is it OAuth2 compliant?

Comment: I don't use any authentication mechanism in the function. The function is dumb and only does what is the bare minimum. However, I use Firebase auth in my iOS and web apps.

Answer (score 2):

Cloud Functions gen2 is backed on Cloud Run. Therefore, Cloud Run authentication mechanism apply.

Because you use Firebase auth, you can refer to that page that explain how to achieve it:
https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/end-users